# Flutter how to open particular screen on clicking on scheduled notification

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification

I send notifications in my app in 2 ways. When I send notifications through FireBase my notification click actions work.
When I send notifications via FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule notifications come in but nothing happens when clicked. How can I setup click actions on scheduled notifications?

```
// my schedule notifications 

Future scheduleNotification(
      {int id = 0,
      String? title,
      String? body,
      String? payLoad,
      required DateTime scheduledNotificationDateTime}) async {
    return notificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        id,
        title,
        body,
        tz.TZDateTime.from(
          scheduledNotificationDateTime,
          tz.local,
        ),
        const NotificationDetails(
          iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
            presentAlert: true,
            presentBadge: true,
            presentSound: true,
          ),
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                'your channel id', 'your channel name',
                importance: Importance.max,
                priority: Priority.high,
                icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
                showWhen: false)),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
  }

// my notification service
class NotificationService {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  AndroidNotificationChannel channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel',
    'High Importance Notifications',
    description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
    importance: Importance.high,
  );

  Future<void> initNotifications() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );


    FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
    if (initialMessage != null) {
      print(initialMessage.data);
      if (initialMessage.data['invoice_id'] != null) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1250))
            .then((value) =>
            navKey.currentState!.push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>
                      WareHouseSalesDetails(
                        id: int.parse(initialMessage.data['id']),
                        invoiceId: '${initialMessage.data['invoice_id']}',
                      )),
            ));
      }
      if (initialMessage.data['moving_id'] != null) {
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1250))
            .then((value) =>
            navKey.currentState!.push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>
                      MovingDetailsPage(
                        id: int.parse(initialMessage.data['id']),
                        movingId: '${initialMessage.data['moving_id']}',
                      )),
            ));
      }
    }

    await messaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification!.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        notificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel.id,
              channel.name,
              channelDescription: channel.description,
              icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
      print(message!.data);
      if (message.data['invoice_id'] != null) {
        navKey.currentState!.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
                  WareHouseSalesDetails(
                    id: int.parse(message.data['id']),
                    invoiceId: '${message.data['invoice_id']}',
                  )),
        );
      }
      if (message.data['moving_id'] != null) {
        navKey.currentState!.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
                  MovingDetailsPage(
                    id: int.parse(message.data['id']),
                    movingId: '${message.data['moving_id']}',
                  )),
        );
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage? message) async {
      print(message!.data);
      if (message!.data['invoice_id'] != null) {
        navKey.currentState!.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
                  WareHouseSalesDetails(
                    id: int.parse(message.data['id']),
                    invoiceId: '${message.data['invoice_id']}',
                  )),
        );
      }
      if (message.data['moving_id'] != null) {
        navKey.currentState!.push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) =>
                  MovingDetailsPage(
                    id: int.parse(message.data['id']),
                    movingId: '${message.data['moving_id']}',
                  )),
        );
      }
    });

    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    const AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_notification');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = const DarwinInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    await messaging.requestPermission();
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      var APNS = await messaging.getAPNSToken();
    }
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `payload`. You can add it to you `zonedSchedule` function like this:

```
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(id, title, body, scheduledDate, notificationDetails, payload: 'my_payload');
```

You can then handle payload by adding `onDidReceiveLocalNotification` method into `flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize`. There you can get payload from details and do whatever you want with it, for example:

```
void initalizeNotifications() {
    // ...
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveNotificationResponse);
}
void onDidReceiveNotificationResponse(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => SecondScreen(payload)),
    );
}
```

Comment: thank you, it works, but is it possible to switch to the screen I need from the terminated state? onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse not working for me

Comment: Try with `flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails()` after initializing the pluign in main function. this is an async function that returns `NotificationAppLaunchDetails` if platform supports it. There you can get payload and pass it to runApp(). The default behavior of notification is that it opens an app it belongs to, so if the app was terminated, `main()` will run. If you're faceing some issues on Android read https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#scheduled-android-notifications because some devices have limitations on scheduling notifications.